# User input stored in an array of char's (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, char

I'm trying to back-up in my programming and learn something that I somehow missed (unless I'm not understanding the problem).  I am trying to prompt the user to enter the name of a project, and I want to store that name in a variable.  Normally I would use `getline()` or `std::cin >> std::string some_string` but the assignment is asking me to do this, without the use of strings.  "You can NOT use the string class - instead use array's of characters."  Therein lies the question: How do I take the user input and store them in an array of chars?

The user is going to enter a word and then hit enter...  How do i capture that into an array of chars?  If the word was coming in one char at a time I could just add it to the array, dynamically expanding if needed, but when it comes in a block of char's like that I am lost for ideas.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The member function [`cin.getline()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/getline/) allows you to specify a character buffer and length.

```
char name[32];
cin.getline(name, 32);
```

Though any C++ assignment that would ask you specifically to use character arrays instead of strings (especially in this context), is suspect.

Comment: `cin.getline(name, sizeof(name));`

Comment: @karl: Dangerous, because if `name` is changed to a pointer, it still compiles but does the wrong thing.

Comment: Of course, but this suggestion goes hand in hand with what is stated in the answer. If @Chad had used pointers, I would not have left my previous comment. :)

Comment: And that is why I say if an assignment is forcing you to use character arrays for this it is suspect.  My guess is an old-fashioned "C with classes!" approach.

Comment: @karl: But it's fairly straightforward to use one of the `countof` implementations instead, which is completely safe.  If you're going to replace the hard-coded constant with a computation, you might as well use the right computation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
char arr[100];
cin >> arr;
```

Comment: Terrible idea.  No way to guarantee the buffer won't overflow.  This kind of thing leads to bugs down the road.

Comment: Note: You must **never** do this after you finish this programming course. You have created a buffer overflow, which is the root cause of various security bugs.

Comment: Call `cin.width(100);` beforehand.

Comment: @Amardeep: No way to guarantee it?  Sure you can, just define `template <size_t N> istream& operator>>(istream&, char (&)[N])` and check the length `N` therein.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: That's plenty clever but does adding obscurity make a poor solution better than an intrinsically safer solution like Chad's?

Comment: @ Rob Do you have real life example on the buffer overflow security bugs? I am interested in learning about them.

Comment: @Amardeep: That trick (which I didn't invent) makes Chad's solution safer as well, by using the actual dimension of the array instead of relying on the user to pass it correctly.